# LoopingSelector all items on the same place

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an application in Windows Phone 8 that I use a `LoopingSelector`. Now I want to choose what item that should be selected through code and because of that I set the selected item of the data source.

However when I do this all the items get stacked on top of each other. Have anyone else got this problem before and how did you solve it?

**Edit, I did miss to put up the `DataSource` code**
My `JokeLoopingSource` (that inherits from my `BaseDataSource`)

```
public class JokeLoopingSource : LoopingDataSourceBase
{
    private readonly IList<JokeEntity> _objects;

    public JokeLoopingSource(IList<JokeEntity> objects)
    {
        _objects = objects;
        SelectedItem = _objects.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void SetSelectedItem(int index)
    {
        SelectedItem = _objects[index];
    }

    public override object GetNext(object relativeTo)
    {
        JokeEntity item = relativeTo as JokeEntity;
        if (item == null || item.Index >= _objects.Count-1)
        {
            return _objects[0];
        }

        return _objects[item.Index + 1];
    }

    public override object GetPrevious(object relativeTo)
    {
        JokeEntity item = relativeTo as JokeEntity;

        if (item == null || item.Index == 0)
        {
            return _objects.LastOrDefault();
        }

        return _objects[item.Index - 1];
    }
}
```

My BaseDataSource

```
public abstract class LoopingDataSourceBase : ILoopingSelectorDataSource
{
    private object _selectedItem;

    public abstract object GetNext(object relativeTo);
    public abstract object GetPrevious(object relativeTo);
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_selectedItem, value))
            {
                object previousSelectedItem = _selectedItem;
                _selectedItem = value;

                OnSelectionChanged(previousSelectedItem, _selectedItem);
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectionChanged;

    protected virtual void OnSelectionChanged(object oldSelectedItem, object newSelectedItem)
    {
        EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> handler = SelectionChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new SelectionChangedEventArgs(new[] { oldSelectedItem }, new[] { newSelectedItem }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to show use what you have did so far.Code or xaml ?

Comment: All the datasources looks pretty simular and my thaught was more if someone did know yeah this is the common problem you get here. But sure I can put out the source code.